# Business Inteligence Tools for MongoDB(Textual Files)

Tags: mongodb, business-intelligence, nosql

Just going through the concepts of Business inteligence for Relational Databases. There Present lots of Tools for Relational DB's.
I want to know is there any tool which is used to do BI for NOSQL(MongoDB) and if yes then which is more powerful.
I have heared about Nucleaon BI. But dont know how powerful it is and advantages above other tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are currently 3 major BI platforms for MongoDB ecosystem.

1. **Jaspersoft** :
   The only BI server that can connect directly to MongoDB, leveraging the aggregation framework APIs, so that you can report on and analyze data in MongoDB without having to move the data through ETL to a relational database.
2. **Pentaho** :
   Increase Data Value – With Pentaho, MongoDB data can be accessed, blended, visualized and reported in combination with any other data source for increased insight and operational analytics. Reduce Complexity – Reporting on data stored in MongoDB is simplified, increasing developer productivity with Pentaho’s automatic document sampling, drag and drop interface and schema generation. Accelerate Data Access and Querying– With no impact on throughput, this integration builds on the features and capabilities in MongoDB, such as the Aggregation Framework, Replication and Tag Sets.
3. **JSON Analytics** :
   Native JSON handling – no mapping to dimensions and measures means very short up-and-running times and no changes when the structure of the data changes. Contrary to previous-generation BI tools, JSON Studio was built from the ground up for JSON and MongoDB and is not based on a connector that tries to map JSON data into columns.
   Native usage of MongoDB’s aggregation framework under an easy to use UI means very fast response times, for the first time accessible to all types of users.
   HTTP Gateway with parameters means power users can design reports and graphs that can be used by any user, used for building dashboards and used from within other applications.
   Rich d3 visualization and exploratory analytics gives power users the perfect platform to understand and work with data.
   Low cost.

**Nucleon BI** is also in the picture but not so popular.
I have used Jaspersoft and found it great for BI and reporting.

Comment: there is also a document from mongoDB, mentioning possible BI solutions: http://info.mongodb.com/rs/mongodb/images/MongoDB_BI_Analytics.pdf (page 10)